# Performance of simple c++20 coroutines looks bad. Is this unavoidable? Is this cost of "frame-switching"?

Tags: c++, performance, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am working with C++20 coroutines, specifically simple generators, but I have observed similar results with coroutines replacing state machines based on boost::msm.

Actually my goal is to provide recommendation to my team about when to use c++20 coroutines after upgrade from c++17 to C++20 move. So these examples are just to help making this recommendation, they are not real code to fix.

I have [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/RA2AZS8NMuSLZJ8H0euoDKBhzFE) that show, in the case of simple generators, the performance of such coroutines can be 4x (gcc13, -O3) or 3.5x (clang17, -O3) worse than functionally identical code based on iterators.

The full code is available under this [link](https://quick-bench.com/q/RA2AZS8NMuSLZJ8H0euoDKBhzFE); the following is just an example code for creating a Cartesian product of two ranges:

- Reference code

  ```
  void cartesian(auto const& xx, auto const& yy, auto body)
  {
      for (auto x : xx) 
         for (auto y : yy)
             body(std::make_pair(x, y));
  } 
  // usage: cartesian(container1, container2, [&](auto const& x_y) { .... });
  ```
- Its "coroutine" equivalent

  ```
  template <typename T> struct generator { /*something similar to C++23 std::generator */ };

  template <typename XX, typename YY>
  generator<std::pair<typename XX::value_type, typename YY::value_type>>
  cartesian(auto const& xx, auto const& yy)
  {
      for (auto x : xx) 
         for (auto y : yy)
             co_yield std::make_pair(x, y);

  }

  // usage: 
  // for (const auto& x_y : cartesian(container1, container2)) 
  // { .... }
  ```
- Functionally identical code based on iterators

  ```
  template <typename R1, typename R2>
  class cartesian_combine
  {
  public:
      explicit cartesian_combine(const R1& r1, const R2& r2) 
          : xx(r1), yy(r2)
      {}

      struct iterator_sentinel {};

      template <typename It1, typename S1,
                typename It2, typename S2>
      struct const_iterator
      {
          const_iterator(It1 xx_begin, S1 xx_end,
                         It2 yy_begin, S2 yy_end)
              : xx_begin(xx_begin), xx_it(xx_begin), xx_end(xx_end),
                yy_begin(yy_begin), yy_it(yy_begin), yy_end(yy_end)
          {
              if (yy_it == yy_end) { xx_it = xx_end; }
          }
          const It1 xx_begin;
          It1 xx_it;
          const S1 xx_end;
          const It2 yy_begin;
          It2 yy_it;
          const S2 yy_end;

          bool operator==(iterator_sentinel) const {
              return xx_it == xx_end;
          }
          auto operator*() const {
              return std::make_pair(*xx_it, *yy_it);
          }
          const_iterator& operator++() {
              if (++yy_it == yy_end) 
              { 
                  ++xx_it; 
                  yy_it = yy_begin; 
              }
              return *this;
          }
      };

      auto begin() const { return const_iterator<
          decltype(xx.begin()), decltype(xx.end()),
          decltype(yy.begin()), decltype(yy.end())
        >{xx.begin(), xx.end(), 
          yy.begin(), yy.end()}; 
      }
      iterator_sentinel end() const { return {}; }

  private:
      const R1& xx;
      const R2& yy;
  };

  auto 
  cartesian(const auto& xx, const auto& yy)
  {
      return cartesian_combine(xx, yy);
  }
  // usage - identical as in "coroutine" case
  ```

It's evident that the "coroutine" code is much simpler than this bug-prone code manipulating a bunch of iterators. However, the performance cost is something that I am genuinely worried about. **So, my question is, I am not sure—probably, this is the cost of switching between frames of the main function and this coroutine. But why is this cost so high?**

[image: result from quick-bench]

In my example, I combine two arrays with 10 elements each, resulting in 100x switchings between these frames (or contexts — I am not sure what the proper terminology is here). Probably, this is not the cost of dynamic memory allocation for coroutine frame because it happens just once, and I even tried returning a preallocated buffer from the generator's promise_type operator new(), but this did not help.

Just in case something is wrong with my generator - the code:

```
template <typename T>
class generator
{
public:
    struct promise_type;
    using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    struct promise_type
    {
        const T* value{};
        std::suspend_always yield_value(const T& v) {
            value = &v;
            return {};
        }

        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() { std::exit(-1); }

        generator get_return_object() { 
            return generator(handle_type::from_promise(*this)); 
        }
    };

    explicit generator(handle_type h) : handle(h) {}
    ~generator() 
    {
        if (handle)
            handle.destroy();
    }
    generator(generator&& other) 
        : handle(std::exchange(other.handle, {}))
    {}

    generator& operator=(generator&& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            if (handle) handle.destroy();
            handle = std::exchange(other.handle, {});
        }
        return *this;
    } 

    struct iterator_sentinel {};
    struct const_iterator
    {
        handle_type handle;
        bool operator==(iterator_sentinel) const {
            return handle.done();
        }
        const T& operator*() const {
            return *handle.promise().value;
        }
        const_iterator& operator++() {
            handle.resume();
            return *this;
        }
    };

    const_iterator begin() const { return {handle}; }
    iterator_sentinel end() const { return {}; }

private:
    handle_type handle;
};
```

Comment: Likely the dynamic allocation that's causing this

Comment: Did you try to profile it?

Comment: coroutines use the heap (not stack) so even just copy of the parameters are not going to be easily optimised by the compiler. Frankly, just stick with the for loop version - simple is best, every time.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - the results are from linked quick-bench.com side https://quick-bench.com/q/RA2AZS8NMuSLZJ8H0euoDKBhzFE. It is - as I can see - `gcc13, -O3`. As I wrote - similar results are for clang. I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - maybe I should mention it - my task is to provide recommendation for hundred of developers if they should or should start using C++20 coroutines when we switch C++17 -> C++20. So - this is just an example - not a real problem to solve.

Comment: There is also [std::ranges::cartesian_product_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/cartesian_product_view). Here is [updated test](https://quick-bench.com/q/XqjPoamqa89eBQP0cddlSekRSWA)

Comment: @Slava - no I did not profile it. I just started with it. I'll probably do - but I need to have setup for this (and time) - so it takes days.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - I replaced dynamic allocation with static allocation (by defining operators new and delete in promise_type). That did not help - I mentioned about that in my, probably too long, question.

Comment: @MarekR - thanks - at least I see my by-hand implementations of iterators is pretty much similar to this std::range solution in terms of performance. But my goal is not to solve this particular example. My goal is to provide recommendation to my team when and if  to use C++-coroutines after switching c++17->c++20

Comment: @PiotrNycz my advice for everything is "don't use the new, cool stuff unless you have a very good reason to use it. Because its cool and new is not reason enough". As it is, it [looks like they're garbage](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/c++-coroutines.html).

Comment: @PiotrNycz - Indeed I missed that. I suppose it's primarily a matter of implementations gaining experience. I wonder how MSVC will fare in this benchmark.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Coroutines make the code shorter, more readable and maintainable - AFAI tried. I mean - it is visible in this question example - but I also have comparison with state machines based on boost::msm vs. c++20 coroutine. And coroutines code is 10 times shorter and it is really visible what going on in coro code. So this is not just "fancy"; only this performance and some other problems - like more dangling references - stop me from doing final recommendation...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Note that generator-style coroutines are not *all* of what C++ coroutines are. They're not even the primary intended application of the technology.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes I know. I tried also to replace state machines based on boost::msm with c++20 coroutines. There - the performance decrease is not so big - about 25% for very simple cases. I need to check also more complicated state machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The range cross product and iterator code does nothing besides manipulate indexes, and a single memory load.  If it wasn't for the hard coded "don't optimize" it would optimize down to doing nothing.

The coroutine code does *not* optimize down to doing nothing, because it sets up the ability to do arbitrary actions, and it does type erasure.

If your operations are empty, coroutines are a bad idea.

If, however, your operations are as cheap as a single memory allocation, the difference almost completely disappears.

```
static void coro_combine_test(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]>> buff;
    for (auto _ : state) {
      for (auto x : coro_combine(xx, yy)) {
        buff.emplace_back( new int[x.first*x.second] );
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x);
      }
      buff.clear();
    }
}
BENCHMARK(coro_combine_test);
```

here I add a memory allocation (of 4 to 400 bytes) per visited element, and then I free them at the end of each iteration.  This represents a bit of non-trivial computation being done.

When I do that, I get 13,000 for the iterator and range versions, and 15,000 for the coroutine version.

Coroutines, as implemented in C++, are not suited to replace per-pixel operations, where the amount of iteration far dominates the amount of work done in the iteration.  Your benchmark is a good way to show this.

If you did a similar test using a type-erased iterator of any kind you'd get similar overhead problems; this isn't specific to coroutines, but to type erasure.

A way I usually handle this is to ensure that the chunks of data I'm iterating over are non-trivial in type erased code.  For example, if I'm iterating over pixels, my runtime type-erasure is at the level of scanlines or blocks of scanlines.

Any higher resolution type erasure I make it compile-time, so I can write per-pixel operations, have my compile-time template rewrite it into block or scanline operations, then feed those block or scanline operations into the type erased (iteration) or (coroutine) or whatever system.

```
void ForeachScanline( MyImage* pImage, std::function<void(std::size_t y, std::span<MyPixel>)>);
template<class F>
void ForeachPixel( MyImage* pImage, F f ) {
  ForeachScanline( pImage, [&f](std::size_t y, std::span<MyPixel> pixels) {
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < pixels.size(); ++x) {
      f(MyLocation{x,y}, pixels[x]);
    }
  });
}
```

the runtime type-erased scanline implementation is used by a compile-time type-erased pixel implementation.  This means that the runtime type-erasure overhead occurs far less often; the scanline loop can be inlined and mixed with the per-pixel operation.

The decision to make coroutines require type erasure led to this result.  Compiler writers had issues with doing it without type erasure, as the size of a coroutine is difficult to determine early enough.  A type erased coroutine can have its size determined before its body is fully understood.

Comment: That is really good observation, that for C++20 coroutines doing something non-trivial - their extra cost resulting from frame-switching and frame-allocation can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

While expecting generator-style coroutines to be exactly as efficient as non-generators is usually incorrect, the scale of the performance difference suggests either that your `generator` object (or the way it gets used) is inhibiting optimizations, or that your compiler's generator optimizations are immature at the present time.

Your particular use case ought to be good for triggering generator optimizations, but they don't seem to be happening.

Comment: I still do not have access to  C++23 std::generator. I added my simple implementation (done just for this exercise) to the question now. I think it is nothing particulary wrong with it, but if you have time - please look.

Comment: GCC trunk on Compiler Explorer has `std::generator` now, but the older GCC on QuickBench doesn't.